# Imu topic not showing in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, sdf, ros-noetic

I am trying to create a gazebo simulation for two wheel robot. When I added the camera model I can see it's topic but when I am adding imu I am not able to see it's topic. I am not sure what is wrong. I am using Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0. I have checked /opt/ros/noetic/lib, the pugin is present.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.4'>
  <model name="d_diff_drive_robot">
    <!-- No Physics -->
    <!--<static>true</static>-->
    <!-- Physics -->
    <static>false</static>
    <!-- Box/Chasis -->
    <link name='chassis'>
      <pose>0 0 .1 0 0 0</pose>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>.4 .2 .1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>.4 .2 .1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <!-- Caster -->
      <collision name='caster_collision'>
        <pose>-0.15 0 -0.05 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>.05</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>0</mu>
              <mu2>0</mu2>
              <slip1>1.0</slip1>
              <slip2>1.0</slip2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name='caster_visual'>
        <pose>-0.15 0 -0.05 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>.05</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <!-- Left Wheel -->
    <link name="left_wheel">
      <pose>0.1 0.13 0.1 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>.1</radius>
            <length>.05</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>.1</radius>
            <length>.05</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <!-- Right Wheel -->
    <link name="right_wheel">
      <pose>0.1 -0.13 0.1 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>.1</radius>
            <length>.05</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>.1</radius>
            <length>.05</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <!-- Axel -->
    <joint type="revolute" name="left_wheel_hinge">
      <pose>0 0 -0.03 0 0 0</pose>
      <child>left_wheel</child>
      <parent>chassis</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <joint type="revolute" name="right_wheel_hinge">
      <pose>0 0 0.03 0 0 0</pose>
      <child>right_wheel</child>
      <parent>chassis</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <link name="cam_link">
      <pose>0.0 -0.05 0.2 0 0 0</pose>
      <sensor name='cam_sensor1' type='camera' always_on='1' update_rate='10'>
        <origin pose='0 0 0 0 0 1.57'/>
        <camera>
          <horizontal_fov angle='1.57'/>
          <image width='640' height='480' format='R8G8B8'/>
          <clip near='0.5' far='5'/>
        </camera>
        <plugin name='gazebo_ros_camera_controller' filename='libgazebo_ros_camera.so'>
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
          <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
          <cameraName>camera</cameraName>
          <imageTopicName>/camera/image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>/camera/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
          <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
          <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        </plugin>
      </sensor>
    </link>
    <joint name="camera_joint_2" type="fixed">
      <child>camera::link</child>
      <parent>chassis</parent>
    </joint>

    <!-- IMU Link -->
<link name="imu_link">
  <pose>0.0 0.0 0.15 0 0 0</pose>
  
  <inertial>
    <mass>0.01</mass> <!-- Assuming a small mass for the IMU -->
    <inertia>
      <ixx>1e-6</ixx> <!-- Placeholder values, you may want to use real values if available -->
      <ixy>0</ixy>
      <ixz>0</ixz>
      <iyy>1e-6</iyy>
      <iyz>0</iyz>
      <izz>1e-6</izz>
    </inertia>
  </inertial>
</link>

<!-- Joint to attach the IMU to the chassis -->
<joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
  <child>imu_link</child>
  <parent>chassis</parent>
</joint>

<!-- IMU Sensor Definition -->
<gazebo reference="imu_link">
  <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
    <always_on>true</always_on>
    <update_rate>100</update_rate>
    <visualize>true</visualize>

    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
      <topicName>/imu/imu_sensor</topicName>
      <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
      <updateRateHZ>10.0</updateRateHZ>
      <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
      <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
      <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
      <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>



  </model>
</sdf>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<gazebo>` tag is only used when using URDF files--it's an [SDFormat extension to URDF](http://sdformat.org/tutorials?tut=sdformat_urdf_extensions&cat=specification&). Since you're actually using SDFormat here, you should put the contents of `<gazebo>` directly inside the referenced `<link>`.

So it would look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.4'>
  <model name="d_diff_drive_robot">
    <!-- No Physics -->
    <!--<static>true</static>-->
    <!-- IMU Link -->
    <link name="imu_link">
      ...
      <!-- IMU Sensor Definition -->
      <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
        <always_on>true</always_on>
        <update_rate>100</update_rate>
        <visualize>true</visualize>

        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>

        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
          <topicName>/imu/imu_sensor</topicName>
          <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
          <updateRateHZ>10.0</updateRateHZ>
          <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
          <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
          <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
          <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
        </plugin>
      </sensor>


    </link>
    ...


  </model>
</sdf>
```